# Eclipse 4.5.1 server timeouts it is not well rendered

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I've this strange behavior of Eclipse 4.5.1 and STS 3.7.3 as shown in the  picture

[image: STS 3.7.3 Server Timeouts malfunction]

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 but also my colleague with Xubuntu 14.04 has the same problem.

I cannot know how many seconds and it is very hard to edit them. The only way I found ctrl-A to select everithing and copy paste.

Anybody knows what it is?

Comment: for what type of server do you observe this? Tomcat? Pivotal tc Server?

Comment: This is for the tomcat 7 adapter

Answer (score 1):

Does resizing the editor help?
Timeouts section in the editor is coming from Eclipse WTP
Think you should raise a bug against Eclipse WTP component Tomcat server integration.

Comment: Unfortunately, no effect resizing the editor. Thank you for your help. I think I'm gonna try to raise this bug.